# Is it possible to see state data inside vault?

Tags: corda

Can we see states inside the vault through h2 database web application? 
If yes, how? All I see is transaction_id and other details but not the data inside the state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the state to be stored in a readable format in the H2 database, it must implement the `QueryableState` interface.

See the docs at https://docs.corda.net/api-persistence.html and the example at https://github.com/corda/cordapp-example/blob/release-V3/java-source/src/main/java/com/example/state/IOUState.java.